# Centering the gnome terminal or console window on start-up

Tags: command-line, gnome, 22.04, gsettings

Using Ubuntu 22.04, I want either my gnome terminal or console to start centered on the screen. Bard AI told me to use this command:
gsettings  set  org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences  center-new-windows true

I got an error message that the key doesn't exist which I confirmed by using the gsettings list commands.

So how do I accomplish my goal?

Comment: Who is this? Bard AI told me to use this command:

Comment: Bard AI is google's AI program. It explained subsequently that the "center-new-windows" key only works in the latest release of Ubuntu - not in 22.04.

Comment: xdotool run as a startup script. might delay it, or loop , to wait for your startup apps to start. thwen along these lines, but with a position center (if that is an xdotool option, or get your screen res.  xdotool  getdisplaygeometry
 and do maths on that to centre)..  Annot, replace with terminal name.

name=$(ps -A | grep Annot)
id=$(echo $name | cut -c1-6)
echo "$id"

i=$(xdotool search --pid "$id")
xdotool getwindowname "$i"
xdotool windowactivate --sync "$i"
xdotool windowsize "$i" 1000 1050

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to not use gnome-terminal in the first place. I installed Sakura terminal emulator and it works great. You've also got to use a desktop entry file that calls Sakura instead of gnome-terminal. Apparently Ubuntu's next release will improve on gnome but there is no way to simply upgrade 22.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

With a little bit of googling I was able to find what's the issue with the command and an alternative solution as well, there are mainly two ways :

1. Correct your above command to the following :

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.mutter center-new-windows true
   ```
2. Through Gnome Tweaks.

   1. Install the package using command :

      ```
      sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
      ```
   2. Once installed, inside of it navigate to the "Windows" tab change the
   3. Toggle for "Center windows" to true

This is how it will look like within the Gnome Tweaks tool:

[image]

**Explanation for 1.:**
I believe the property has been moved to a different schema (from `org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences` to `org.gnome.mutter`) due to which the error which you have mentioned above is thrown and so using the right schema fixes the error. (ref: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2023/04/center-new-windows-ubuntu-gnome)